# how to read multiple text files into a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, databricks

i have a few txt files in a directory(i have only the path and not the names of the files) that contain json data,and i need to read all of them into a dataframe.

i tried this:

```
df=sc.wholeTextFiles("path/*")
```

but i cant even display the data and my main goal is to preform queries in diffrent ways on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **`wholeTextFiles`**(gives key, value pair having key as filename and data as value),

Try with **`read.json`** and give your directory name spark will read all the files in the directory into dataframe.

```
df=spark.read.json("<directorty_path>/*")
df.show()
```

[**From docs:**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles)

```
wholeTextFiles(path, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True)
```

> Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system
>   (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI.
>   Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair,
>   where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of
>   each file.
>
> Note: Small files are preferred, as each file will be loaded fully in
>   memory.